# Color code from different class doesn't show propper color in main class Swift?

Tags: swift, image, colors, swiftui

I'm trying to extract the color from a separate class to my view but when I call it like this the color just shows Black[image: BlackDot] instead of orange[image: OrangeDot]. How can this be?

```
struct Small: View {
    
    var styling: ViewStyling?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 10, height:10)
                    .foregroundColor(styling?.orangeDot) <--- Color should be Orange
                    .padding(.trailing, -4)
               }
          }
     }
```

Color class looks like this.

```
class ViewStyling {
    
    var orangeDot:Color = Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6784313725, blue: 0.262745098, alpha: 1))
    
}
```

Comment: Is `styling?.orangeDot` nil? Is `styling` `nil`? Has it been set?

Comment: How are you setting `styling` on `Small`? You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created ViewStyling object so, it return nil.
First, Create ViewStyling object.

```
struct Small: View {
    
    var styling: ViewStyling = ViewStyling() //<-Here
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 10, height:10)
                .foregroundColor(styling.orangeDot)// <--- Color should be Orange
                .padding(.trailing, -4)
        }
    }
}
```